# split by <br> and avoid strong tags in string

Tags: javascript

i have below html code in my native language, which i'm trying to convert into an array that i can process. So what i want is split this into an array where it avoid strong tags and split by `<br>`, but not add an empty object with the last `<br>`

so far i have this

```
var ingredients = $('div.ingredients p').html().replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '').split("<br>");
```

**html**

```
<p>
    <strong>Dressing: </strong>
    <br>
    2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 % 
    <br>
    1 lille spsk god mayonnaise
    <br>
    1-2 tsk æbleeddike 
    <br>
    1-2 tsk honning 
    <br>
    himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber
    <br>
</p>
```

desired output

```
["2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 %", "1 lille spsk god mayonnaise", "1-2 tsk æbleeddike", "1-2 tsk honning", "himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber"]
```

Comment: what do you exactly want as the output?

Comment: added desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever want to go native ES6 Javascript:

```
function split(selector) {
  const elem = document.querySelector(selector);
  const content = elem && elem.innerHTML;
  if (!content) { return null; }

  return content
      .split('<br>')
      .map(it => it.trim())
      .filter(it => !!it && !it.startsWith('<strong>'));
}
```

Use with:

```
const res = split('div.ingredients p')
console.log(res);
```

Output is:

```
["2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 %", "1 lille spsk god mayonnaise", "1-2 tsk æbleeddike", "1-2 tsk honning", "himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber"]
```

Comment: What if a strong tag is in the middle in the p tag is it possiple to just filter all strong tags out of it.

Comment: Try the code :-) That's the purpose of .filter() call, it removes all blocks that will start with a strong tag, whatever their position.

Comment: y but in some other cases where the strong tag is in the middle of the p tag, it does not seem to filter it away :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop()` to remove last element.

```
var ingredients = $('div.ingredients p').html().replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '').split("<br>");

ingredients.pop();

//[" Dressing:  ", " 2-3 spsk græsk yoghurt, gerne 10 % ", " 1 lille spsk god mayonnaise ", " 1-2 tsk æbleeddike ", " 1-2 tsk honning ", " himalayasalt og friskkværnet hvid peber "]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the last br might be there or not ( or worse that there can be multiple br's), the best thing can be filter out empty elements after the split

something like:

```
$('div.ingredients p')
  .html()
  .replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '')
  .split("<br>")
  .filter(function(e) { return e.trim() !== ''})
```

Also I sense that you have to replace , and \n with ''